# How do I change the url for shared links with owncloud?

Tags: owncloud

I installed owncloud with [owncloudpie](https://github.com/petrockblog/OwncloudPie), so everything was done for me by magic.  When a user shares via a link, they get https://192.168.x.x/... I've actually got a vanity url that maps to my home machine so https://vanity.com/... works.  Where do I change what root url gets shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public link that is sent out, as far as I know, is assembled from the URL you're accessing ownCloud under when you create the share. So one option is to also access ownCloud via that `https://vanity.com/..." url when creating the share.

Another option, I think, would be to change the [overwritehost](https://github.com/owncloud/core/blob/master/config/config.sample.php#L39) setting in your config.php; that should also always be used; but it also has other sideeffects.